# sfinae with decltype of comma operator: bug in clang or gcc?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, sfinae

```cpp
struct data_t
{
    template<class T>
    auto foo(T t)
    {
        t + "";
    }
};

template<class ...Ts>
void bar(Ts&&...)
{}

template<class T>
auto bar(T h)->decltype(h.invalid, h.foo(&h))
{}


void test_bar()
{
    data_t h;
    bar(h);
}
```

### The above mentioned codes are accepted by clang 10+ (ref: https://godbolt.org/z/MM7habqY1) but rejected by gcc 10+ (ref: https://godbolt.org/z/5W6Gv6Wqx ), regarding c++14/17/20 standard.

Obviously, clang skips further parsing when finding *h.invalid*, and then SFINAR kicks in.
However gcc tries to look into both operands of comma operator, which causing a hard error because of instantiating a function template with error.

C++20 standard said in $13.10.3.1 (Template argument deduction):

> The expressions include not only constant expressions such as those that appear in
> array bounds or as nontype template arguments but also general expressions (i.e., non-constant expressions)
> inside sizeof, decltype, and other contexts that allow non-constant expressions. The substitution proceeds
> in lexical order and stops when a condition that causes deduction to fail is encountered

Also we know that for built-in expression (E1, E2), E1 is sequenced before E2.

My best bet is that clang is correct. The key point is *lexical order* and/or *sequenced before*.

My question is:
Which one conforms c++ standard regarding this corner case in SFINAE relevant to unevaluated expression?

Comment: I asked chatGpt in term of this issue. The answer is interesting:

Comment: The answer is junk. There's no coherent explanation why this happens, nor standard references.

Comment: Sequenced-before doesn't seem to be relevant as nothing in the expression gets executed.